# Issue with anchor in chrome

Tags: html, anchor

I set up a single page layout so I'm using anchor tags as part of my site navigation. All of them are working except the portfolio tag. When I select portfolio from my menu, the screen jumps down to the proper section and then immediately moves to the section above.

I'm not sure if there is some interference from any of my other code, or if the animation of the "solutions" pictures/text is creating the issue but I can't seem to solve it on my own.

Something to note is that the link does work, but only when you already have portfolio selected (ex. /#portfolio)

My site is http://muvltd.com

Any idea?

Comment: On second click it's coming to the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your anchors. The problem is that the orange circles in the solutions section are not displayed until you scroll down, so they are not yet rendered into the page. This gives the portfolio section a higher absolute position in your page. Chrome jumps to your section which first works fine. But when the solutions section is loaded it pushes down the portfolio.

If you know the exact height of the solutions section or the images contained in the section, I suggest you assign this height to the respective elements. This way, all dimensions are set correctly before the content is actually loaded / initialized.

Comment: I figured it had to be the animation as well so I removed it just to make sure. Even with no animation, the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, in my original code, the anchor tag was outside of the paragraph tags:

```
<p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 55px;">[maxbutton id="5"]</p><a id="portfolio"></a>
```

Putting them inside the tags solved the problem:

```
<p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 55px;">[maxbutton id="5"]<br><a id="portfolio"></a></p>
```

I can't tell you why it would make a difference but it did, thanks for the help!